# How to Prove $a \equiv a^{-1} \pmod b$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $a = b - 1$; $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.
$a \equiv a^{-1} \pmod b $

So far I've got...
$a \equiv a^{-1} \pmod b$

*multiply all by a* 
$a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod b$

*substitute* 
$(b-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod b$

Not sure how to finish the proof. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Just finish.  $(b-1)^2 = b^2 -2b + 1 = b(b-2) + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod b$. !!!BUT!!!! this is not a proof.  You started by assuming what you need to prove and ending up with a true statement that $1\equiv 1 \pmod b$.  That is not a prove.  That is just a demonstration that you don't always have a contradiction.

Comment: Oml I feel so silly that I didn't manage to finish it from there! Ty so much for showing me how to finish it.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4111477/is-m-1-1-%e2%89%a1-m-1-mod-m-when-m-is-a-prime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^2 \equiv 1\pmod b$

$(b-1)^2\equiv 1 \pmod b$

$b^2 -2b + 1 \equiv 1\pmod b$

$b(b-2) + 1 \equiv 1\pmod b$

$1 \equiv 1\pmod b$

So you have proven that $a = b-1$ and $a\equiv a^{-1}\pmod b$ then $1\equiv 1 \pmod b$.

Which is *NOT* what you were asked to prove.

You can *NOT*  do a proof by *assuming* what you *need* to prove and ending up with a true statement.  All that proves is that *maybe* $1\equiv 1\pmod b$ but only if we already know for a fact that $a\equiv a^{-1} \pmod b$.

This in no way shows us that $a\equiv a^{-1} \pmod b$.  It just shows you don't always get a contradiction.

We start with what we *know*

$a = b-1$  then we want to show if we multiply by $a$ we will get a congruence to $1$.

$a = b-1$ so

$a\cdot a = (b-1)(b-1)=b^2 -2b + 1=b(b-2) + 1$ so

$a\cdot a \equiv 1 \pmod b$.  We didn't *assume* it.  We showed it.

So $a \equiv a^{-1} \pmod b$.

.....

It may be even easier to note that if $a = b-1$ then $a \equiv -1\pmod b$.  So $a^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod b$.  So $a\equiv a^{-1}\pmod b$.

.....

But *PLEASE* tattoo it to your forehead that you do not *ever* start a proof by assuming what you need to prove.

Answer (score 1):

$$a \equiv b - 1 \equiv -1 \ (mod \ b) $$
because $b \equiv 0 \ (mod \ b)$, so $$a^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \ (mod \ b)$$
$$a\cdot a \equiv a \cdot a^{-1} \equiv 1 \ (mod \ b) \longrightarrow b\ | \ a(a - a^{-1}) $$
But $mdc(a, b) = mdc(b -1, b) = 1$, so $b\ | \ (a - a^{-1}) \longrightarrow a \equiv a^{-1} \ (mod \ b)$